# Generate a random string from NSCharacterSet

Tags: objective-c, nscharacterset

I have the following NSCharacterSet and want to generate a random string valid for that character set.

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSMutableCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];

[characterSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

`[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:]` produces a character set out of a string. I want a method that does the opposite. Something like `[NSString stringWithCharacterSet:]`

Comment: Well, you'd pretty much have to generate a random `unichar` value and test it's membership in the set.  You could perhaps speed things along by first doing a "census" with haveMemberInPlane, to find what ranges are possible.

Comment: You have to do something more than say "gimme the code".

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `NSCharacterSet` is the best way to store the list of valid characters as it doesn't provide convenient methods to get its length or access a character at a particular index.  Use `NSString` instead:

```
+ (NSString *)randomStringFromCharacters:(NSString *)chars
                                ofLength:(NSUInteger)length
{
    unichar str[length];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; i++)
        str[i] = [chars characterAtIndex:arc4random() % [chars length]];

    return [NSString stringWithCharacters:str length:length];

}
```

Comment: And if one *had* to start with a character set, one could spin through the set once to build the list of valid characters, then select from that list.